# Word/phrase for "process of joining a group or a club"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Example:

> Mary began telling about her [...] to the club.

I thought of the word *initiation* but I think an initiation is more like a "rite." I'm looking for something that just means the process of joining a group or a club.

Comment: *joining* - Mary began talking about her joining the club.

Comment: *talking about* is more appropriate, with *telling* it's best to use a complement/object e.g. Mary began telling Peter about her... You could use "chatting" instead of "telling". *Mary began chatting about her membership to the club*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> She was **inducted** into the club.
>   She was **initiated** into the
>   club.

The opposite in meaning would be...

> She was **blackballed** by the club.

Answer (score 3):

If there is even a slightly structured joining process you could use the word "***[enroll](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enroll)***" (US) or "enrol" (UK):

> to become a member or participant

"Mary talked about enrol[l]ing in the science club".

or, to fit your example:

"Mary began talking about her enrolment..."

Answer (score 0):

> She was admitted to the club.

or

> Mary began telling about her admittance to the club.

Answer (score 0):

> Mary began talking about her admission to the club.

At least that's what I have seen the Financial Times use in terms of being invited into an organization (as fine a reference on English usage as any I know): https://www.ft.com/content/92dbb440-14bc-11de-8cd1-0000779fd2ac

I don't think admittance is wrong, but it carries a sense of authorization. You may be admitted to the club grounds once you have gained admission to the club.

Enrollment feels suitable if you're referring to the administrative process of joining an organization. But again, it is upon admission that you would typically enroll.

Answer (score 0):

How about "accepted" into the club ?